# How to extract cookies from a REST Assured response using common code

Tags: java, rest-assured

Using REST Assured (4.3.3, from Java) I can freely manipulate request and response specification objects in a base test class, so that when the actual test needs a request specification to execute the actual call, it's "pre-configured" with certain common statements. For example:

```java
public abstract class TestBase
    protected RequestSpecification request() {
        return given()
                .cookies(globalCookies)
                .port(serverPort)
                .log().ifValidationFails()
                .then()
                .log().ifValidationFails()
                .given();
    }
}
public class ActualTest extends TestBase {
  @Test
  public void test1() {
    String content = request().get("/some").then()
           .statusCode(200)
           .extract()
           .body().asString();
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do now is to "pre-configure" the specifications to preserve cookies between the requests. I am feeding the list of cookies to send using `RequestSpecification.cookies(Cookies)`, but I can't find any way to instruct the specifications to extract the returned cookies before obtaining the instance of `Response`. However, such instance is only available after calling one of the `RequestSender` methods, which I can't do in the base code.

The methods I've considered to solve this are outlined below, but the first two are quite clunky, and the third is probably just outright wrong as it meddles with classes in "internal" sub-packages. Is there a "right" way of doing this?

1. Add a base method `saveCookies()` that takes in an instance of `ValidatableResponse`, on which it can call `extract()`, and get the cookies. Then each test will have to use the method.

```java
public abstract class TestBase
  // ...
  protected ValidatableResponse saveCookies(ValidatableResponse r) {
    saveGlobalCookies(r.extract().detailedCookies());
    return r;
  }
}
public class ActualTest extends TestBase {
  @Test
  public void test1() {
    String content = saveCookies(request().get("/some").then())
           .statusCode(200)
           .extract()
           .body().asString();
  }
}
```

2. Use a base method that takes in lambdas so that the potentially intermediate `ValidatableResponse` can be intercepted, and the final result (if needed) returned to the invoker.

```java
public abstract class TestBase
  // ...
  <T> T cookieRequest(Function<RequestSender, ValidatableResponse> exec, Function<ValidatableResponse, T> post) {

        ValidatableResponse vr = exec.apply(request());
        saveGlobalCookies(vr.extract().detailedCookies());
        return post.apply(vr);

    }
}
public class ActualTest extends TestBase {
  @Test
  public void test1() {
    String content = cookieRequest(r->r.get("/some").then(),
       r->r.extract().body().asString());
  }
}
```

3. Instantiate extended instances of `ResponseSpecificationImpl` (dragging in `RequestSpecificationImpl` and `TestSpecificationImpl`).

Comment: Did you take a look at `CookieFilter`. No need to keep track cookies every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CookieFilter` to satify your need.

> The cookie filter can be used to keep track of all the cookies sent by
> the server and use them in subsequent requests

You can use this class in 2 ways:

1. Static setting:

```
RestAssured.filters(new CookieFilter());
```

2. Specify for request you want:

```
CookieFilter cookieFilter = new CookieFilter();

//Request 1  
given().filter(cookieFilter).get("/x");

//Request 2
given().filter(cookieFilter).get("/y");
```

For more information:

- CookieFilter [class](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/rest-assured/src/main/java/io/restassured/filter/cookie/CookieFilter.java)
- CookieFilter [test class](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/rest-assured/src/test/java/io/restassured/filter/cookie/CookieFilterTest.java)